# Show that a function is not continuous under the product metric

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, continuity, metric-spaces

Let X be the linear space of all bounded real sequences, and let $ f: X \rightarrow R $ be defined as $f := \sum^{\infty} 2^{-i}x_i $. Show that $f$ is not continuous when normed by the product norm.

The solution is this:

Consider $(x_m)$ with $x_{m,i} = 2^{-i} \mathbf{1}_{i = m}  \forall m,i \in N$; $(x_m) \rightarrow 0$ in the product metric but $f(x_m) = 1 \forall m \in N$ whereas $f(0) = 0$.

What I don't understand is why $f(x_m) = 1 \forall m \in N$.

I guess I am confused because I don't understand the construction of the $(x_m)$ sequence. I think $i$ is the index for the order of each element in the sequence, but what is $m$ the index for? I thought it is just a way to name a sequence? How can there be $\mathbf{1}_{i = m}$ in the construction of a sequence?

Really appreciate any explanations since I am a bit confused. Thank you.

Comment: The use of $\forall$ in the quoted solution is ghastly. Your instructor needs some instruction about good notation.

Comment: $\sum 2^{-i}x_i$ is in fact continuous, since $\left|\sum 2^{-i} x_i\right| \leq \left(\sum 2^{-i}\right) \cdot \lVert x\rVert_{\infty}$, and that geometric series converges. I would presume that $f$ should be defined with $2^i$ instead of $2^{-i}$.

Comment: What do you mean by the product norm? There is a product metric but no product norm.

Comment: For each $m$, $x_m$ is a bounded sequence of real numbers. Its $i-$th  term is denoted by $x_{m,i}$.

Comment: There is probably a typo. I think it shouldbe $x_{m,i}=2^i \mathrm{1}_{i=m}$.